# same author same year of publication natbib

Tags: citing

I wanted to cite  the same Author and same year of publication paper and I want to cite them like `(Rupke,2005a,b,c)` or `(Rupke,2005a)`,`(Rupke,2005b)` etc. The latex code i added below is giving me an error. Any help? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citep{Rupke2005a},\citep{Rupke2005b,Rupke2005c}
\end{document}
```

Here is also the `.bib` file in my file name called `proj.bib`:

```
@article{Rupke2005a,
author = {Rupke, David S and Veilleux, Sylvain and Sanders, D B},
file = {:home/melaku/Documents/Master project/papers/petri4444me.pdf:pdf},
pages = {87--114},
title = {{Keck High-Resolution Spectroscopy of Outflows in Infrared-luminous Galaxies}},
year = {2005}
}

@article{Rupke2005b,
author = {Rupke, David S and Veilleux, Sylvain and Sanders, D B},
file = {:home/melaku/Documents/Master project/papers/petri 4 pr.pdf:pdf},
pages = {115--148},
title = {{Outflows in Infrared-Luminous Starbursts at z 〈 0.5. I. Sample, Na I D Spectra, and Profile Fitting

Show affiliations
}},
year = {2005}
}

@article{Rupke2005c,
author = {Rupke, David S and Veilleux, Sylvain and Sanders, D B},
file = {:home/melaku/Documents/Master project/papers/petri 3 pr out flow.pdf:pdf},
pages = {751--780},
title = {{Outflows in active galactic nucleus/starburst-composite ultraluminous infrared galaxies 1,2,3}},
volume = {3},
year = {2005}
}
```

Comment: Your sample code is missing both a `\bibliographystyle` directive and a `\bibliography` directive. Unsurprisingly, BibTeX throws error messages in such cases.

Answer (score 3):

For that, you should specify an author-year style for your bibliography. For example the `apalike`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\citep{Rupke2005a},\citep{Rupke2005b,Rupke2005c}

\bibliography{proj} % <== you must say where your bib entries are
\bibliographystyle{apalike} % <== and here you specify the style for your bibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

For other options of author-year styles, see the [natbib documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf).

Comment: The `apalike` bibliography style can generate only authoryear-type citation call-outs. Other styles, including `plainnat` and `abbrvnat`, can generate numeric-style *and* authoryear-style citation call-outs. In such cases, it's necessary to set the option `authoryear` explicitly while loading `natbib`. If authoryear-style citation call-outs are needed, I think it's always a good idea to specify the option `authoryear` when loading `natbib`. If the bibliography style you happen to use cannot generate authoryear-style citatino call-outs, you'll get a helpful warning message.

Comment: @Mico, thanks for your comment. I'm a biblatex person myself, so not very acquainted with natbib styles. If you feel like editing the question to add this information, please be welcome. Or if you care to provide another more complete one, I woudn't be troubled at all, on the contrary.

Comment: @Mico  Thanks but still  not working,  seems you have changed something from .bib file coz I already did that, doesn't make any difference though.What did u change exactly to .bib file?

Comment: @MelakuSisay, I just copy-pasted your entries to a file named `proj.bib` in the same directory as the main tex file. Are you aware that you must build your document with `pdflatex` -> `bibtex` -> `pdflatex` -> `pdflatex` ?

Comment: yes I am aware Since I'm using overleaf its automatically  pdflatex -> bibtex -> pdflatex -> pdflatex setted.

Comment: @MelakuSisay, then we need more details as to what means "still not working". What exactly goes wrong? Do you get errors? Or results are different from the expected? Do the problems appear even if you use the above simplified example, or only in your full document?

Comment: That's my question too.No error, it only gives me something like this (?) but the rest of the document works very well, so the part that doesn't work is when I have same author- same year of publication cases like mentioned above.what exactly do u use in your case inside  .bib file? did u change any thing?can u answer this question as well?

Comment: @MelakuSisay, in this case, you should take a careful look in this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63875/105447 . As I told you, I didn't change a comma in the bib file. And I tested the example in overleaf, with the same (and expected) results. (You might try though overleaf's "recompile from scratch" option).